# Deploying QT application

Tags: qt

I try to deploy my QT Application build on Windows with VC++(Debug mode). I run the application on a PC on which QT is not installed. I also provided some .dll libraries that it requires. Here is the folder layout:

1. D3DCompiler_43.dll
2. icudt49.dll
3. icuin49.dll
4. icuuc49.dll
5. libEGLd.dll
6. libGLESv2d.dll
7. MyApp.exe
8. MyApp.ini
9. Qt5Cored.dll
10. Qt5Guid.dll
11. Qt5Widgetsd.dll
12. plugins
13. plugins\platform\
14. plugins\platform\qminimal.dll
15. plugins\platform\qminimald.dll
16. plugins\platform\qwindows.dll
17. plugins\platform\qwindowsd.dll

When i run the application i get an error saying:"Failed to load platform plugin 'windows'. Available platforms are:"
I think it can not find a platform to load altough i provided platforms under the plugins folder. I also add the platform path to system path but it didn't solve also. Any suggestion?

Comment: While all the answers are already given, I would like to comment. I see that all Qt-libs in your list have `d` at the end, what means that these are *debug* version of them. To reduce files size you may want to deploy *release* build of your app, in that case you will need to distribute *release* versions of Qt libs with it (without `d`).

Comment: I have similar problems. Deploying Qt4 was very easy, it only needed QtGui and QtCore. Now we need a dozen more DLLs :( , and even after providing the DLLs it usually doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *plugins* directory is [unnecessary](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#qt-plugins).

Try this structure:

- ...
- Qt5Widgetsd.dll
- platform\
- platform\qminimal.dll
- platform\qminimald.dll
- platform\qwindows.dll
- platform\qwindowsd.dll

Answer (score 3):

There is a [help page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) which tells in detail how to deploy Qt5 applications for Windows.

The most helpful info from there: There is a Windows deployment tool (windeployqt) which finds all required dlls automatically for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can load your plugins at the start of the program `main()` as follows:

```
QCoreApplication app(argv, args);    
QString sDir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
app.addLibraryPath(sDir+"/plugins/platform");
```

Comment: I think this is useful for plugin dlls. But what about the core .dlls? If core .dlls are besides the .exe, then it works but it does not work if it is in another folder.. i also tried adding the folder to path but it did not work..

Comment: that is usually for plugins. without `core dlls` in same directory with your exe, your application cannot even start. basically, you cannot move core dlls from exe directory to other directory.

Answer (score 0):

When running Qt in Debug, the output window tells you all the DLLs it loads, and which you then need to inclde in your distribution exe folder.